# How to detect dom change in acceptance testing with selenium and codeception

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, acceptance-testing

I am writing an acceptance test for application written in angular. I use Codeception testing framework with selenium. The test writes some text into input field and submits form. It should add new task to db through ajax api call and add new  `<li>` element to the list of existing tasks. 
How would I detect that the new element was added? Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?php
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('add new story');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->fillField('input', 'asdf');
$I->pressKey('input[name=input]', '13');
// ensure that new <li> has been added?
```

Comment: Is the new element is added in the end of the list or anywhere in the middle of the list?

Comment: It's added to the beginning

Answer (score 1):

you may write the code to click li using anyithe following way

//Accessing via div tages

```
$I->click('div div div div div ul li a');
$I->see('UNIT 1');
```

//Accessing via classname

```
$I->click('div[class="new"] div div div a');
```

//Accessing via div ids

```
$I->click('div[id=tnList] ul li a');
```